# Getting a source clip from iMovie

Tags: imovie

Last year I imported a video into iMove, edited it, cut pieces, etc and I have the result as a mov, but I want to also keep the original video file. I can still see it inside iMovie, but how do I get ahold of that file as a single simple file system file?

Answer (score 1):

The iMovie Library file is actually a folder…
Right click it & 'Show Package Contents'

Then the original file is inside [movie name] > Original Media

You can drag a copy out to any other location. Keep the original in place, or iMovie will lose it.